# Does $\int_1^\infty \sin (x\log x)\ dx$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, integration

> Does $$\int_1^\infty \sin (x\log x) \ dx$$ converge or diverge?

I've tried some substitutions ($u = x\log x$, $u = \log x$).
Also, I know that the integral $\int_1^\infty \sin x \ dx$ diverges, which leads me to think our integral behaves in the same manner.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651951/does-the-integral-int-1-infty-sinx-log-x-mathrmdx-converge

Comment: @Crostul, isn't that a risky theorem? since the integrand gets positive/negative values.

Comment: @Crostul: That claim is **false**. $\int_0^\infty \sin(x^2)\ dx$ exists despite the integrand oscillating continuously back and forth between $0$ and $1$. See `http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate[Sin[x^2],{x,0,Infinity}]` for an exact value! Edit: Crostul removed his comment; his claim was that the integral does not converge because the integrand does not converge to zero. I'll leave this here in case other people make the same mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: First prove that $f = ( x \mapsto x \ln(x) )$ is an increasing function on $[1,\infty)$. Next let $y$ be the increasing sequence such that $f(x) = n π$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$, and prove that $y_{n+1}-y_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Then since $f$ is increasing show that the sequence $A = ( \int_{y_n}^{y_{n+1}} \sin(f(x))\ dx )_{n\in\mathbb{N}^+}$ is alternating with absolute value going to zero. Thus the integral $\int_1^\infty \sin(f(x))\ dx$ converges, as it is bounded between adjacent partial sums of $A$.

Comment: This $y_n$ sequence exists because $f$ is a continuous function, though I don't know how to explicitly isolate $y_n$ from $y_n\cdot \ln y_n = n\frac{\pi}{3}$.

Comment: I guess it doesn't really matter if I can't explicitly express $y_n$ as long as we know there's such sequence.

Comment: @Elimination: Right there is no need to explicitly express the sequence. All that is important is that $f$ is continuous as you said so that the intermediate value theorem works, and that it is monotonic so that the integral can be bounded.

Comment: Why does the absolute value of the sequence not tend to zero? If I'm not mistaken, $y_{n+1}-y_n$ tends to $0$ and each integral is bounded by $1\times(y_{n+1}-y_n)$, hence tends to $0$ as well.

Comment: @Wojowu: Oh wait you are right; exactly the same reason as the example I gave in the comment.

Comment: @Elimination: I've fixed my answer. Wojowu, thank you very much!

Comment: How do you know that the integral's absolute value going to zero? is it because $(n+1)\pi - n\pi \to 0$?

Comment: @Elimination: $| \int_{y_n}^{y_{n+1}} \sin(f(x))\ dx | \le \int_{y_n}^{y_{n+1}} |\sin(f(x))|\ dx$

Comment: Oops. I wrote a nonsense statement,but I still don't get it :/

Comment: @Elimination: What do you not get? The inequality I just wrote is a basic one, and also $|\sin(x)| \le 1$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh okay. So we have $\le \int_{y_n}^{y_{n+1}} 1 \ dx = y_{n+1} - y_n \to 0$

Comment: @Elimination: Yes and now check the sign of each integral. An alternating sequence with terms going to zero has convergent partial sums. Finally check that the in-between integrals are bounded between the adjacent partial sums.

Comment: And the fact that $A_n$ is alternating sequence is a simple trigonometric fact.

Comment: @Elimination: Right.

Comment: Then, by Leibniz Theorem we conclude that $\sum A_n < \infty$.

Comment: Many thanks @user21820!