Evaluating $\int_1^{\infty } \sin (x \log (x)) \, dx$
I looked around a bit and it seems that an analytical form for this integral is out of reach:
$$\int_1^{\infty } \sin (x \log (x)) \, dx$$
Still thought of asking here once. Does anyone know of an analytical form? It could be in terms of special functions or a sum/product series.
The numerical value seems to be around $0.7139878$.
There are a couple of posts which discuss the convergence of the integral e.g. Does the integral $\int_{1}^{\infty} \sin(x\log x) \,\mathrm{d}x$ converge?. Those show that the integral converges in a certain sense, and here I am particularly interested in the form of the integral.

see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/651951/1157207

The above question does not evaluate the integral explicitly or fully.
